# Is it nessesary to use PWM pin on LMD18200

Tags: pwm, h-bridge

I'm creating the circuit which has to apply direct and inverse voltage to the load and I want to use LMD18200. According to it's truth table, if I connect PWM to logic `HIGH` it will work just as needed. However, two Chinese ICs have already passed away.

So, am I doing something wrong by connecting PWM to a steady voltage or it is the problem of non-genuine ICs?

On the picture below J1 is the connector to controller (+5V, direction and SGND). The controller uses the same power supply so GND and SGND have equal potential. 
[image]

Edit:
The circuit was tested with equivalent resistor instead of voice coil, so it's not the inductance effects which had killed the chip.

Using the oscilloscope I've found strange signal in that resistor, It looked like output voltage was a square wave instead of a steady current. (Current was less than 1 Amp, so no overcurrent protection should be involved.)

If I increase power supply voltage to about +25V, the current through the chip (not through the testing resistor) suddenly increase to more than 3 Amps (when I saw this, I've immediately turned of the whole setup).

Edit2:
The **purpose** of the circuit is to drive voice coil of HDD, but for testing I've used 10 Ohm resistor instead of voice coil (its active resistance is 8.5 Ohm).

In first test with the supply voltage around +15 volts I've measured square signal on that Resistor instead of steady current. The total power supply current through the whole setup was 0.1 Amps, the chip was not warmer that room temperature.

In the second test the supply voltage was increased and when I've reached +25V the current jumped to 3 Amps (that was power supply ammeter shows), so I've immediately turn everything off. After that the chip was warm, but not more than 45 Celsius (110 Fahrenheit), as I was able to handle it without pain.

Comment: what do you mean with "Chinese ICs"?

Comment: It were bought from Aliexpress and its cost was significantly less than TI recommended. It is possible, that the ICs are just not what they seem to be.

Comment: what was the *equivalent* resistance?

Comment: how is the chip mounted?  Heatsinked?

Comment: The measured active resistance of the voice coil was 8.5 Ohms, I've used the 10 Ohms resistor.

Comment: No, the chip wasn't heatsinked, but it wasn't heated too. I've touched it between measurements and it wasn't even warm.

Comment: Please get all the relevant facts straight!  Is it 100mA or 1Amp?  Is it a resistor or a motor or  a voice coil?  Chasing your answers around is tiresome...

Comment: If your chip really burned out from just increasing the supply voltage to +25V, sounds to me like you bought defective parts at a discount. It's certainly been known to happen when buying from taobao/aliexpress. Probably worth it to just buy from a legitimate distributor

Comment: You have two capacitors in series with your voice coil.  A steady current through the voice coil is therefore **not** possible.

Comment: Steady current through resistors connected in parallel to capacitors is possible. Capacitors is needed to increase current through the coil just after direction change, but it's not the point of the question.

Comment: If you bought questionably sourced components, they're going to have the potential to behave in questionable ways.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are abusing the chip.  The inputs are tied in the test configuration from the datasheet.  The brake is tied to ground, so never used. The PWM is tied high, so 100% duty cycle and the direction pin is switched at will.

Let's try a quick analogy.  *What happens when you are on the highway in your car going 60mph and you put the gear selector into reverse?*
Maybe you should **come to a stop first** so you don't break the transmission or damage the car in some other way.

Electric motor circuits aren't much different.

Also you could add a bidirectional TVS diode across the motor to help absorb the back emf spikes from when you transition directions.

[image]

Pick one that is about double your HV supply voltage, as that is what will be present when you attempt to reverse a spinning motor.

**UPDATE**

In the comments it is stated that the inductance is not a motor, but a voice coil with a small inductance.   Well let's look at that.  Here is the voltage equation for an inductor:

\$v=L\frac{di}{dt}\$

\$L=100uH\$?

\$i=100mA\$

\$t=?\$

When you switch directions the current goes from 100mA to 0mA to -100mA, so total magnitude of that change is 200mA.  Therefore \$di=200mA\$.

But what about \$t\$?

If the output of the LMD18200 (TI's web page isn't loading right now, so I can't verify) switches in say 100ns then:

\$v=100uH*\frac{200mA}{100nS} = 200V\$  That is much higher than the 50V max of the part!
​

Comment: It's not the motor, but HDD voice coil. It has relatively small inductance and the measured current through the coil is about 0.1 Amps.

Comment: Small inductance, or big inductance, the physics are the same.  When the signal is reversed there is a large voltage spike.

Comment: I've edited the question. This IC was burned in the test with resistor instead of voice coil. Yes, I have to add TVS diode to my circuit, but it's not the cause of that failure.